# Why FindFirstFileW always return -1?

Tags: winapi, unicode, syntax, vb6

`FindFirstFileA` (ANSI) works as it should, while `FindFirstFileW` (Unicode) not. 
The Wide version always return -1 (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE), but why?

```
'Declarations:
Option Explicit

Private Const MAX_PATH  As Long = 260
Private Const ALTERNATE As Long = 14
Private Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Long = -1

Private Type FILETIME
    dwLowDateTime  As Long
    dwHighDateTime As Long
End Type

Private Type WIN32_FIND_DATA
        dwFileAttributes As Long
        ftCreationTime As FILETIME
        ftLastAccessTime As FILETIME
        ftLastWriteTime As FILETIME
        nFileSizeHigh As Long
        nFileSizeLow As Long
        dwReserved0 As Long
        dwReserved1 As Long
        cFileName As String * MAX_PATH
        cAlternate As String * ALTERNATE
End Type

Private Declare Function FindFirstFileW Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal lpFileName As String, _
    ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long

Private Declare Function FindFirstFileA Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal lpFileName As String, _
    ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long

Private Declare Function FindClose Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal hFindFile As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Integer

'Test Functions:
Public Function TestA(ByVal sf As String) As Long
    If Len(sf) < 3 Then Exit Function
    Dim wfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA
    TestA = FindFirstFileA(sf, wfd)
    'Debug.Print "AE:" & GetLastError()
    If TestA <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then FindClose TestA
End Function

Public Function TestW(ByVal sf As String) As Long
    If Len(sf) < 3 Then Exit Function
    Dim wfd As WIN32_FIND_DATA
    TestW = FindFirstFileW(sf, wfd)
    'Debug.Print "WE:" & GetLastError()
    If TestW <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then FindClose TestW
End Function

'Example test
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim sDir As String
    sDir = "C:\new"
    MsgBox "A: " & TestA(sDir) & vbCrLf _
         & "W: " & TestW(sDir)
End Sub
```

**P.S.** Thanks to Carey Gregory, but I still need a bit of help to translate Wide version. What's the equivalent of C/C++ `WCHAR` in VB6?

```
//WinBase.h
typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAA {
    DWORD dwFileAttributes;
    FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    DWORD nFileSizeHigh;
    DWORD nFileSizeLow;
    DWORD dwReserved0;
    DWORD dwReserved1;
    CHAR   cFileName[ MAX_PATH ];
    CHAR   cAlternateFileName[ 14 ];
#ifdef _MAC
    DWORD dwFileType;
    DWORD dwCreatorType;
    WORD  wFinderFlags;
#endif
} WIN32_FIND_DATAA, *PWIN32_FIND_DATAA, *LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA;
typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAW {
    DWORD dwFileAttributes;
    FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    DWORD nFileSizeHigh;
    DWORD nFileSizeLow;
    DWORD dwReserved0;
    DWORD dwReserved1;
    WCHAR  cFileName[ MAX_PATH ];    //WCHAR in VB6?
    WCHAR  cAlternateFileName[ 14 ]; //WCHAR in VB6?
#ifdef _MAC
    DWORD dwFileType;
    DWORD dwCreatorType;
    WORD  wFinderFlags;
#endif
} WIN32_FIND_DATAW, *PWIN32_FIND_DATAW, *LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIN32_FIND_DATA has two versions just like the functions that use them: an ANSI version and a Unicode version.  You need to define WIN32_FIND_DATAA and WIN32_FIND_DATAW and use them appropriately with the 'A' and 'W' functions.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how the W version w'd like?

Comment: As you obviously understand because of your `TestA` and `TestW` functions, there are separate Win32 API functions for ANSI and Unicode text.  Those functions require separate WIN32_FIND_DATA structures as well since that structure contains text data.  Take a look at the WIN32_FIND_DATA definition in winbase.h and it should be obvious what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still need a bit of help. See my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after re-reading [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205277) I found my mistake. It's not about separate WIN32_FIND_DATAW type, but need to declare `FindFirstFileW` arguments as `Long` and `ByVal`.

```
Private Declare Function FindFirstFileW Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal lpFileName As Long, _
    ByVal lpFindFileData As Long) As Long
```

And also need to call them with `StrPtr` and `VarPtr`.

```
TestW = FindFirstFileW(StrPtr(sf), VarPtr(wfd))
```

Comment: You would still need to define two separate WIN32_FIND_DATA structs because the Unicode version of FindFirstFile is going to return a WIN32_FIND_DATAW struct.  I'm no VB expert, but my understanding is you can define a WCHAR in VB using ChrW.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I think that VB version of WIN32_FIND_DATAW is impossible, and of course, in case someone know the way, I'll appreciate corrections.

Comment: It's not impossible at all.  Just declare cFileName and cAlternateFileName as Byte with a length of MAX_PATH * 2 and 14 * 2, respectively.  Examples of using WCHAR types in VB6 are all over the web.  For example, [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?365738-Classic-VB-Does-Visual-Basic-6-support-Unicode).

Comment: I appreciate your help and I see sense in your suggestion, looks like it work. But I found varied values for Byte arrays, like for ex. `cFileName(1 To (260 + 16) * 2)` and `cAlternate((14 * 2) - 1)`, and can't be sure which is correct. Also perhaps more advanced test necessary before telling concrete advantages/disadvantage of both ways. For now I think to stick with what the most vb-guys do, i.e. going like in my answer.